# What is the difference between file_get_contents and fread

Tags: php, file, file-io

What is the difference between

```
$contents = file_get_contents("folder/somefile.txt")
```

and

```
$handle = fopen("folder/somefile.txt", "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
```

in terms of performance, file pointer handling and memory managing ?

And is it true that file_get_contents uses `mmap` if OS allows it ?

Answer (score 6):

fread has a limit on how many chars you can read, and its better for parsing data.

file_get_contents has no limit on the input (that I know of). This is used for external API access and such.

Comment: correct that I was having issue with `fread`. It was truncating characters of serialize data while reading from file.

Comment: file_get_contents has also an optional parameter for offset and length.
If not provided it reads the entire file.

In the examples of Benjamin Crouzier in both example the entire file is read in.
Beside the fact that it is less work to write file_get_contents instead of fopen, fread and fclose to read a file I'm curious if there is a huge performance difference.

Also noticable that file_get_contents works with wrapper like an URL for example.
@Benjamin Crouzier
Where do you get the info that file_get_contents use mmap if available?

Comment: Refering to https://petermoulding.com/php_file_performance_options file_get_contents should be slower than fopen, fread, an fclose.
I've done a benchmark myself reading 1000 times the same file.
In In 183 of 1000 file_get_contents was faster and in 817 of 1000 f_reads was faster, but only a few milliseconds.
So I would assume that both functions are equal in performance and which one is the faster depends on the state of the environment (load, file system, hardware ...).
If you're not working on a real time application, I would recommend using file_get_contents instead of fread.

Answer (score 5):

`fread()` reads binary data, `file_get_contents()` returns the data as a string.

Comment: I am comparing the two snipets of code, and i like you to condider also `performance, file pointer handling and memory managing`

Comment: Wrong - with `fread()` you should open file with `b` flag to ensure that it's binary-safe, while `file_get_contents()` is always binary-safe

Comment: I like your comment @Crack. By the way nice answer by Organized

Comment: file_get_contents : This function is binary-safe.

Answer (score 2):

Curious results! The file_get_contents() function is supposed to be a wrapper for fopen, but the decoupling of the fopen and fread seems to make performance slower.
http://www.ebrueggeman.com/blog/php_benchmarking_fopen

Comment: The domain www.ebrueggeman.com is on sale, so it is impossible to read the benchmark.